STM32L431VC reading single channel ADC from multi channel set up
I am using a STM32L4 MCU which has 1 ADC with 16 channels. I am using 3 channels to get data from different sensors. I want to get voltage levels from these sensors by selecting which input channel to read.
Currently I set up scan mode, which reads all three sensors values. I also planning on implementing DMA and Conversion complete interrupt. Is this possible?
I tried looking for HAL function for single channel read but found nothing.
Which mode and set up should be used to be able to read any of 3 ADC1 channels at any given time without scanning through all enabled channels?

What does the reference manual for your controller say?

can't find any info or don't understand it. Discontinuous mode seems like it, but don't know for sure.

If you want to read values from different channels at different times, the easiest way is to read all the inputs through circular DMA, and in the software, you simply look at the individual values. Circular DMA can tell you when the buffer has been filled, if that’s important for you.
I don't see a reason why you should change the ADC settings every time to read a random input at a random time. However, it is possible by changing the analog multiplexer settings before reading the input. You change the analog multiplexer settings after stopping the ADC like this:
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0; // SELECT CHANNEL
sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER; // ENABLES SELECTED CHANNEL
sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE; // DISABLES SELECTED CHANNEL
if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}

This is how you can enable and disable the ADC inputs. After changing the settings, you can start the ADC in any mode.
I hope this helps.

The only reason I can think of to not read all the channels all the time is if that method doesn't get you to the sample rate you need, but that's not a problem the OP specifies.

it seems like reading all channels if I'm only interested in 1 at specific time is a bit overkill. It's a bit strange that you can't read just 1 channel.

Hi, I don't think it's overkill because the entire operation runs on hardware. Thanks to the DMA controller, reading all channels and storing them in RAM doesn't consume any CPU cycles. You simply turn it on and can forget about it; the hardware will do its job.
I thought of another option, using Injected channels, assuming your processor has them. They should do exactly what you need – read an individual channel whenever you need it. However, I don't have much experience with them, so I'll leave that to you.
